# How do you bypass having to manually save during Photoshop batch processing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have over 600 JPG images, and I need to apply the same action to all of them and then have them saved to a new folder. I tried batch, but after each image it brings up the JPG options dialog asking me to choose compression and what not. I want it to just save it automatically. How can I do this?

Note: I already tried "Override Save As Commands" and after it's done the destination folder is always empty.

Comment: The above link shows a few options how to batch large files.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Also record the save action during recording for batch